# How to do multi label classification of the below problem? Pandas Python

Tags: python, pandas, logistic-regression

My original data looks like this.
The purpose is to build a model that predicts whether the home/away team wins or the match is drawn

```
 df.head()
    id  season   home_team  away_team  home_goals  away_goals result winner
0   0   2006-07  SHU        Liv        1           1          D    NaN
1   1   2006-07  Ars        AVL        1           1          D    NaN
2   2   2006-07  Eve        Wat        2           1          H    Eve
3   3   2006-07  NEW        WA         2           1          H    New
4   4   2006-07  Por        BR         3           0          H    Por

df.columns

Index(['id', 'season', 'home_team', 'away_team', 'home_goals', 'away_goals',
       'result', 'winner'],
      dtype='object')
```

I selected these 3 columns and label encoded them

```
 df[['home_team', 'away_team','winner',]].head()
```

As for outcome variables I created these new features:

```
df.loc[df["winner"]==df["home_team"],"home_team_win"]=1
df.loc[df["winner"]!=df["home_team"],"home_team_win"]=0

df.loc[df["result"]=='D',"draw"]=1
df.loc[df["result"]!='D',"draw"]=0
```

I considered these both as my classes (**home_team_win** and **draw**)

Below, I wrote the code for **home_team_win** class, I applied second class **draw** in same code, which is giving me error mentioned below. I think RFE doesn't support multiple classes in my case.

```
X = prediction_df.drop(['home_team_win','draw'] ,axis=1) # X

y = prediction_df[['home_team_win','draw']] # y
```

When I use a single class **"home_team_win"** no error occurs, But when I place **"draw"** as a 2nd class the following error occurs

```
logReg=LogisticRegression(solver='lbfgs')

print('logReg', logReg)

X.shape
out[]:
(4560, 2)

y.shape
out[]:
(4560, 2)

rfe = RFE(logReg, 20) # 20 is test percentage

rfe = rfe.fit(X, y.values.ravel())

print('rfe', rfe)

#Checking for the features of they are important

print(rfe.support_)
```

**Error:**

**ValueError: Found input variables with inconsistent numbers of samples: [4560, 9120]**

Prediction System will predict **home team win** percentage and **draw** percentage.

The prediction result will be:

```
Home Team Win 60%
Draw 20%
```

Comment: Could you give a small sample of your data and the complete error output?

Comment: I have provided all the necessary data and information

Answer (score 1):

You need to decide whether you are predicting your two labels (draw or no draw, home win or no home win) independently or you want as 3 different classes (home win, draw, others).

If it's the former, you have two response variables or labels, you cannot flatten them with `.ravel()`. You need to use a [MultiOutputClassifier](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.multioutput.MultiOutputClassifier.html) but this does not work with RFE.

For example:

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
from sklearn.multioutput import MultiOutputClassifier
from sklearn.feature_selection import RFE

X = np.random.uniform(0,1,(200,50))
y = np.random.random(["Win","Draw","Lose"],(200,2))

logReg=LogisticRegression(solver='lbfgs')
clf = MultiOutputClassifier(logReg)
clf.fit(X,y)
```

You can get back the probabilities for each class if you use only 1 response variable, I don't have your data frame but something like this should work:

```
df['label'] = 0
df.loc[df["winner"]==df["home_team"],"label"]=1
df.loc[df["result"]=='D',"label"]=2
```

Then run your logistic regression